# HTTP get to AS is giving 500 error during login

Tags: java, http, get, netweaver

I am trying to login to SAP CE server using java code. I am getting error:

> HTTP status code 500

What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class GetExample {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    GetExample getExample =  new GetExample();
    URL gatewayServiceUrl = new URL("http://192.168.55.12:56400/nwa");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) gatewayServiceUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", getExample.getBasicAuth());
    connection.connect();
    if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
        System.out.println("success");
        System.out.println(getExample.getDataFromStream(connection.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        System.out.println("success");
        System.out.println(getExample.getDataFromStream(connection.getErrorStream()));
    }
    System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    
}
private String getBasicAuth() {
    String userpass = "bpm-vikask" + ":" + "Init-12345";
    return "Basic "
    + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass
            .getBytes());
}
private String getDataFromStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            stream));
    String data = "";
    while ((data = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
        dataBuffer.append(data);
    }
    inStream.close();

    return dataBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A 500 response means "internal error", and indicates that something is wrong on the server side.  I suggest that you check the server-side log files.  There may also be clues in the error stream ... which you are apparently already reading.